# How do you change anything that isn't transparent to black in gimp?

Tags: gimp

I have an Image, and I want to change anything that isn't transparent into black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select black as the foreground colour (or press <kbd>D</kbd> to set default colours: black foreground, and white background)
2. Make sure you have the correct layer select in the Layers panel, then select *Lock alpha channel*

[image]

3. Do *Edit > Fill with FG color*, or use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

[image]

Obviously, once you've finished, unlock the alpha channel if you want to edit the transparent areas again.